# MySQL left join is taking too long to return

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem like I have three tables `tbldispensaries`, `tblStates`, `tblCountries`. I am storing country and state id's in dispensary table and all details related to country and state are in `tblCountries` and `tblStates` respectively.

I am writing a query to find out the nearby dispensaries within a radius of 500 in order to show markers on Google Maps, the query is fine but when I am using left join with the query, it is taking too much time to respond. I have tried using indexing but that too has no affect on it. So please suggest me to overcome this problem. Here under is the query which I am using:-

```
SELECT
    d.id AS disp,
    d.id AS the_id,
    d. NAME,
    d.address AS addr,
    d.city AS city_name,
    c.country_name AS cntry_name,
    s.state_name AS st_name,
    d.zip AS zipcode,
    d.latitude,
    d.longitude,
    (
        6371 * ACOS(
            COS(RADIANS(33.6119)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(
                RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS(- 111.8906)
            ) + SIN(RADIANS(33.6119)) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude))
        )
    ) AS distance
FROM
    `tblDispensaries` d
    LEFT JOIN tblCountries c ON (c.country_id = d.country)
    LEFT JOIN tblStates s ON (s.state_id = d.state)
WHERE
    d.id IS NOT NULL
    AND d. STATUS = 1
HAVING distance < 500
LIMIT 0,60
```

Comment: create index on ID column in both table

Comment: I have already created two indexes in tbldispersaries for country and state.

Comment: Pls share the explain of the query with us along with the create table statemenst for the underlying tables, so that we can see exactly what indexes you have on the 3 tables. However, that filtering in the having clause may be one of the reasons that the query is slow. Have you considered using calculated columns (if your mysql version supports them) and moving the criteria from having into the where clause?

Comment: I suspect that `WHERE/[AND] (6371 *...` will be faster. Also, you can exclude results that fall outside a bounding rectangle (a square) equal to the chosen diameter. This can use a range query, so makes good use of indexes.

Comment: And why would d.id ever be NULL ??? Or is it a sort of '1=1' type gimmick?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer but it is two big to be a comment. Also, I don't have the data so I can't test, but here it is.

```
SELECT 
    Dispensaries.*,
    c.country_name AS cntry_name,
    s.state_name AS st_name
FROM (
  SELECT
      d.id AS disp,
      d.id AS the_id,
      d. NAME,
      d.address AS addr,
      d.city AS city_name,
      d.zip AS zipcode,
      d.latitude,
      d.longitude,
      (
          6371 * ACOS(
              COS(RADIANS(33.6119)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(
                  RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS(- 111.8906)
              ) + SIN(RADIANS(33.6119)) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude))
          )
      ) AS distance
  FROM
      `tblDispensaries` d
  WHERE
      d.id IS NOT NULL
      AND d. STATUS = 1
  HAVING distance < 500 
  LIMIT 0,60
) as Dispensaries
LEFT JOIN tblCountries c ON (c.country_id = Dispensaries.country)
LEFT JOIN tblStates s ON (s.state_id = Dispensaries.state)
```

I suppose that fetching the results and the using a `JOIN` will be faster.